# Why width:100% doesn't work in typahead input?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have included typeahead.js library into my source code to do suggestion task while user type a word inside input form.
But unfortunately the input width cannot be enlarged with %.
This is my code.

Js libraries:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
    <script src="js/googleapis_jquery_min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/typeahead.min.js"></script><!-- TYPEAHEAD LIBRARY-->
    <script src="js/select2.min.js"></script><!-- SELECT2 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.alphanum-master/jquery.alphanum.js"></script>
    <!-- <FANCYBOX> -->
    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
    <!-- </FANCYBOX> -->
    <!-- <MENUBAR> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menubar.js"></script>
```

Typeahead JQuery:

```
 // FORM PENCARIAN SKPD PENGIRIM USULAN PENGANGKATAN JFT Karier
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
       name: 'typeahead',
       remote:'ajax/skpd_pengirim_typeahead.php?key=%QUERY',
       limit : 10
   });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panelcontainer" style="width: 100%;">   
  <div class="bodypanel" id="bodyfilter">
    <table border="0px" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>
       <tr>
          <td>SKPD</td>
          <td width='10px'>:</td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="typeahead" id="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" spellcheck="false" placeholder=". : Ketik SKPD : .">
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*costumizing form input of typeahead*/
    input.typeahead{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```

While the form input can be enlarged with px.

Why is this happenning ?

And how does to fix this ?

[typeahead form input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAC3Z.png)

Please help My Brothers/Sisters.

**UPDATED : **

My typeahead.js was coming from this:
[master.zip](https://github.com/codeforgeek/ajax-box-php/archive/master.zip).

Comment: Invalid markup. Can't have TRs without a TABLE.

Comment: My bad Brother. I've edited my question. Absolutely i puted TRs inside TABLEs.

Comment: For a start, avoid using tables for layout, the `table` tag ahould be for tabular data only. It is 2020, there are **many** better ways to layout a form. By ditching the `table` you will be able to better cater for responsiveness by using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `<tr>` in a `<table>` as @Ultimater suggested, and give the table a width.

```css
/*costumizing form input of typeahead*/

input.typeahead {
  width: 100% !important;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panelcontainer" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="bodypanel" id="bodyfilter">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>SKPD</td>
        <td width='10px'>:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="typeahead" id="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" spellcheck="false" placeholder=". : Ketik SKPD : .">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it Brother, but not change. Please take a look at my updated question.
By the way if i put the class name of input differ with the ```$('input.typeahead').typeahead..``` targeted class name, the either width 100% or 100px would work. But  if i put the class name of input same as ```$('input.typeahead').typeahead..``` targeted  class name, the width 100% wouldn't work, but 100px would work Brother.

Comment: I need 100% for responsive web Brother.

Comment: I don't understand. You can see it working in my snippet, correct? Please include  your JS if you think that's affecting the layout.

Comment: Yes i think so Brother. I've updated my question for the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this attribute to the table

```html
<table style="width:100%">
```

and

```css
input#typeahead {width: 100%;}
```

Comment: I did Brother, but still not change. Please take a look at my updated quiestion.

Comment: input.typeahead { width: 100%; }